# Match two java collections by property avoiding ConcurrentModificationException (example of Google Roads api)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, concurrency, google-roads-api

I haven't found any similar questions, where one collection is accessed while looping through another. Most of the questions about two collections and loops refer to simultaneous looping through both collections.

I'm using Google Road API in my application.
(documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)

Simplified pre-history:

There is a polyline of car route. It should be corrected according to real roads coordinates and then colored according to speed at each point.

So, I have my own RoutePoint object:

```
public class RoutePoint{
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private double speed;  
}
```

Out of `List<RoutePoint> routePoints` I take latitudes and longitudes, construct request to Google Roads Api with interpolate = true and receive my fixed points with real roads coordinates, all good.

Each received `snappedPoint` (as Google calls them) has `originalIndex` property which is the index of each inital point if the request. Since I use `interpolate= true`, size of `snappedPoints` will usually be bigger than `originalPoints` and each interpolated point will have `originalIndex = null`.

```
public class SnappedPoint{
    private SnappedLocation location;
    private Integer originalIndex;
    private String placeId;
}
```

Once I received my `snappedPoints`, my task is to draw colored polylines, depending on speed in each point. In order to do that I need to match original points with snapped points by `originalIndex`. Then, assign speed to each of the `snappedPoints`. So, I add `speed` to `SnappedPoint` class:

```
public class SnappedPoint{
    private SnappedLocation location;
    private Integer originalIndex;
    private String placeId;
    private double speed;
}
```

In order to match original points with snapped points I decided to loop through `snappedPoints` and when `originalIndex` matches `routePoint` index, copy the `speed` to `snappedPoint`:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; snappedPoints.size() > i; i++) {
    SnappedPoint snappedPoint = snappedPoints.get(i);
    RoutePoint routePoint = routePoints.get(counter); //ConcurrentModificationException at this line

    //do my match speed logic, but I can never come to this point
    if (snappedPoint.getOriginalIndex() == null) {
        snappedPoint.setSpeed(routePoint.getSpeed());
    } else {
        if (snappedPoint.getOriginalIndex() <= counter) {
            snappedPoint.setSpeed(routePoint.getSpeed());
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we've come to my problem. I get *ConcurrentModificationException* when trying to access `routePoints.get()`. As far as I understand it's because I'm accessing one collection while looping through another.

How to avoid this exception? 
Or how to match original points with snapped points, avoiding this situation?

Comment: As I understand the reason of the exception is that, some other thread is modifying your `routePoints` list. May be a producer still adding route points. May be you should make a snapshot of your `routePoints` before the iteration, and use that shanpshot in the loop. eg: `List<RoutePoint> snapshot = new ArrayList<>(); snapshot.addAll(routePoints);`

Comment: In that case I get ConcurrentModificationException at `snapshot.addAll(routePoints)`. But thank you for pointing out that another thread is modifying `routePoints`, I actually found the problem, it had nothing to do with the loop. When I find the solution, will post it here.

Comment: Balázs Nemes, my problem was with several AsyncTasks accessing the same `routePoints` list at the same time. But technically, your answer was correct. I created separate snapshot for eash AsyncTask and it worked. Could you post it as answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: thank you it is a really kind offer, but the real solution is yours :)